# Lost OMG Tokens with Bitfinex

Tags: wallets, exchanges

I withdrew 681 OMG tokens to myetherwallet yesterday. The withdraw is showing as completed in the exchange however the tokens didn't arrive in my wallet. I have verified that the address is correct. When looking at the transaction details it shows the following error message:

Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction]

Has anyone else experienced this issue and what was the solution? I have reached out to Bitfinex support and am awaiting their response...

[image: screenshot]

Comment: From your screenshot the transaction has failed, wait for support they should return your tokens on verification that it has failed.

Answer (score 1):

That error message indicates that the contract function threw an Exception.

Without seeing the contract source code it is impossible to guess at what caused that exception.

If it is an error caused by BitFinex, they will need to resolve it appropriately.